# splitting a number using c

Tags: c

the code snippet below takes an an integer (i.e. number) from the user and prints the count of all the digits in that number, however, if I enter a number contains 0 somewhere, it gets out of the while loop immediately (because of the while loop condition). I tried fixing this bug but I could not. Could you please help me out fixing it. Thank you.

```
int count = 0;
int rem = number % 10;

while(rem != 0) {
   number /= 10;
   ++count;
   rem = number % 10;

}//end while

printf("The count is %d", count);
```

No code need to be shared, if you can walk me through it by text, that would appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it should be:

```
while (number != 0)
```

---

You don't seem to need the other stuff (`rem` et al) unless you plan on doing more than just counting digits. And at any rate, you probably want `rem = number % 10;` before the division.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to take the remainder of the number to count every digit. Just keep dividing by 10 until you reach 0:

```
while(number != 0) {
  number /= 10;
  ++count;
}
```

Comment: But the OP wants it to stop if a 0 is found at any point in the number.

Comment: @luketorjussen: But that's the *bug* part that OP has mentioned. He doesn't want it to stop when a 0 is found.

Answer (score 1):

(come on, this is elemantary school maths!)

If there's a zero somewhere, then 0 modulo 10 will result in 0 (what else would you expect?), so it's naturally exiting the loop. What you want is to check whether the number *itself* has been shifted all to the right so it reached 0 finally:

```
while (number != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `while` loop ends when you enter a number with a 0 is because the loop condition is `rem != 0`. If you take a look, `rem` becomes the last digit of `number`. Hence you need `while (number != 0)`, ensuring that you loop through every digit.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in all 4 previous answers, the loop is

```
while(number > 0) {
   ++count;
   number /= 10;
}//end while
```

Another option is to leave the user input as a string (assuming the number is supplied as a parameter to the program) and just print the string length,

```
char number[30];
strcpy(number,argv[1]);
printf("The count is %d\n", strlen(number));
```

Comment: Thank you Alec for the comment. I already took the first approach. thank you for stepping in the conversation.